# Show that V is a vector space.

Tags: vector-spaces

Let V={$p:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}\mid p(x)=p(x+1)$, all derivatives $p'(x), p''(x),...$ exist}.

Show that V is a vector space.

So I managed to prove that zero vector is in the span of V.

And then let $$p_1(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...$$ $$p_2(x)=A_0+A_1x+A_2x^2+...$$

where$$a_1=a_2=...=A_1=A_2=...=0$$

since $p(x)=p(x+1)$.

Then $$(p_1+p_2)(x)=(a_0+A_0)+(a_1+A_1)x+(a_2+A_2)x^2+...$$

Then $$(p_1+p_2)(x)=(p_1+p_2)(x+1)=a_0+A_0$$

Then I stopped because I think something is wrong... Can someone please enlighten me? Thank you!

Comment: Uhhh just noticed the textpipe thing... Why is it not working? I got the command from LaTex...

Comment: \textpipe needs another package. Use \mid instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the zero function is the zero vector.

Furthermore, if $p,q\in V$, then $p(x)=p(x+1)$ and $q(x)=q(x+1)$ for each $x$.
Thus $(p+q)(x) = p(x)+q(x) = p(x+1)+q(x+1) =(p+q)(x+1)$. Hence $p+q\in V$.

Moreover, let $a$ be a real number and $p\in V$. Then $(a\cdot p)(x) = ap(x) = ap(x+1) = (a\cdot p)(x+1)$ and so $a\cdot p\in V$.

Comment: mindblown lol thank you!